# Can you add custom states to Android TextViews?

Tags: android, textview

I'm looking to add new states to a TextView. I chose TextViews because they're a relatively simple controls and I want use this in a widget so I really want to cut down on nested controls as much as possible. I need to define custom states for my TextViews. States like, not_started, in_progress, completed, missed, did_not_do, etc...

I want the background and font color to change with the states. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use a Level-List selector to handle my "custom states" and define my states as integers.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html